# R: using previously determined variable as part of png file name

Tags: r, variables, png

I am still new to R and I have searched around for a solution to my simple question, but I haven't found an answer that I've been able to get to work. I am looking to use a previously identified variable per data set, here variable=SNPname to include in script for automated generation of graph output in png format.

I am using this to generate a kmeans plot and have:

```
(cl <- kmeans(FilteredData[,6:7], 5, nstart=25))
png("C:/temp/$SNPnamegraph1.png")                 #SNPname to include in filename
plot(FilteredData[,6:7], col=cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col=1:5, pch=8)
dev.off()
```

where I want to include that variable in line 2 at the beginning of the file name. Is there a simple way to do this that I am just missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, you're just missing the use of paste() and setwd()

```
setwd("C:/temp/") # use this to set where you want things saved
...
c1 <- kmeans...
png(paste(SNPname, " graph1.png", sep=""))
...
```

If it's in a loop of some kind, you might need to use `SNPname[loop_var]`

Comment: Actually the variable itself will change if we put it in a loop, so that should be perfect. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See also `?file.path` for safe file path construction. Probably not a big issue here, but perhaps convenient.

Comment: @joran: Alas, I wish `file.path` was "safe". `file.path("c:/foo/","bar\\baz")` generates `"c:/foo//bar\\baz"`

Comment: @Tommy - Indeed; "safe" just referred to different platforms, which as I noted, probably isn't an issue here. But it can be a convenient shortcut compared to `paste`ing thing directly.

Comment: @Brandon - Nothing, really. Tommy just pointed out that it doesn't protect you from being dumb and passing it strings with incorrectly placed / or \ in them.

Comment: Also look at the `sprintf` function as an alternative to `paste`, some prefer it for this type of thing.  It works better if you want filenames like 'graph001.png', 'graph002.png', etc.

Comment: @Greg Snow I also use it. For OP problem: `png(sprintf("C:/temp/%sgraph1.png", SNPname))` is more readable than `paste` form.

Comment: @joran - "dumb" is a strong word: `file.path(Sys.getenv("APPDATA"), "Sun/Java")` seems pretty normal IQ to me :)